Connecting Trimble R2 in QuickCapture
I am attempting to connect my Trimble R2 to my iPad 10th generation to use in Esri QuickCapture. I am able to connect the antenna to my device and connect through Trimble Mobile Manager app. However, when I try to set the R2 unit as my location provider in Esri QuickCapture, it fails to connect. The R2 is not connected to another device, the iPad is updated, the applications are updated, and the R2 firmware has been updated to 5.66 as of 2 days ago. Does anyone know what the issue could be?
